# Godaddy database question

Tags: mysql, database, godaddy

Before going for a Godaddy hosting plan I would really like to know what this database limitation means.

I really don't understand what they mean with **10x200Mb** in the database section.

Does that mean:

- The accumulated database size may not be larger than 10x200Mb
- You can only have a max of 10 databases that individually may not exceed 200Mb

So which one is it? And if the second. What happens when a database breaks this quota?

Comment: Have you tried asking godaddy sales or support?

Comment: Don't be silly Womble. That would be akin to reading a manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

10 databases, total of which may not exceed 200 MB is what I was told about 6 months ago when a friend asked me what that meant.

Call them and ask them.  Better yet, call three times and choose the answer you like best.  From what I've seen, even they don't know what their terms mean sometimes.